# Error when creating List Fields, "Request failed. Value does not fall within the expected range"

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, jsom, office-365-developer

Iam getting this error "Request failed. Value does not fall within the expected range" when i create list with choice Field/column and Taxonomy Field.

**Here is my code for creating the List, and then in my second function i create all the Fields:**

```
 var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spHostUrl);
                        var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();

                        var listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
                        listCreationInfo.set_title('GNTiles_');
                        listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.genericList);
                        this.oList = oWebsite.get_lists().add(listCreationInfo);

                        clientContext.load(oList);

                        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                            addGNTilesFieldsToList(gnPagesId, termStoreId, termSetIdProcess);
                            console.log('List GNTiles created..');
                        }, function (sender, args) {
                            console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
                        });
```

Creating all Fields:

```
        var addGNTilesFieldsToList = function (gnPagesId, termStoreId, termSetIdProcess) {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spHostUrl);

        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('GNTiles_');

        this.oField = oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field DisplayName=\'Text\' Type=\'Note\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
        this.oField = oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field DisplayName=\'Class\' Type=\'Text\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
        this.oField = oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field DisplayName=\'TextClass\' Type=\'Text\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
        this.oField = oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field DisplayName=\'ClickAction\' Type=\'Text\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
        this.oField = oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field DisplayName=\'TextAnchor\' Type=\'Text\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
        this.oField = oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field DisplayName=\'ElementType\' Type=\'Text\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
        this.oField = oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field DisplayName=\'TextRotate\' Type=\'Text\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
        this.oField = oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field DisplayName=\'sPropJSON\' Type=\'Note\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
        this.oField = oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field DisplayName=\'GoToPage\' Type=\'Text\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
        this.oField = oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field DisplayName=\'Corner\' Type=\'Text\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
        this.oField = oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field DisplayName="GNPage" Type="Lookup" List="' + gnPagesId + '" ShowField="GNPage" RelationshipDeleteBehavior="None" />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);

        var choiceDropDownField = clientContext.castTo(
        this.oField = oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field Type="Choice" DisplayName="svgShape" Name="svgShape" Format="Dropdown" />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.addToDefaultContentType), SP.FieldChoice);
        var availableDropChoices = Array("circle", "ellipsis", "rect", "path", "polygon", "polyline");
        choiceDropDownField.set_choices(availableDropChoices);
        choiceDropDownField.update();

        var taxFieldProcess =
             '<Field Type="TaxonomyFieldType" DisplayName="Process"  ShowField="Term1033" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE"  StaticName="Process" Name="Process" > \
                 <Default /> \
                 <Customization> \
                    <ArrayOfProperty> \
                        <Property>\
                            <Name>SspId</Name>\
                            <Value xmlns:q2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q2:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">' + termStoreId + '</Value>\
                        </Property> \
                        <Property>\
                            <Name>TermSetId</Name>\
                            <Value xmlns:q2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q2:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">' + termSetIdProcess + '</Value>\
                        </Property> \
                        <Property>\
                            <Name>TextField</Name>\
                            <Value xmlns:q2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q2:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></Value>\
                        </Property> \
                    </ArrayOfProperty> \
                   </Customization> \
              </Field>';

        this.oField = oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml(taxFieldProcess.toString(), true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);

        var fieldNumber = clientContext.castTo(oField, SP.FieldNumber);
        fieldNumber.update();
        clientContext.load(oField);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            console.log('Fields created..');
        }, function (sender, args) {
            console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        });
    }
```

I get this error first time i try to create the List and Fields, List always get created, but NOT the Fields. So each time i have to delte the List, and re-create it, then i dont get this error message. By googling a litle i found that it maybe can be List View Treshold value issue, and i did change the Treshold value without any luck....

How can i fix this?

reg 
gonadn

Comment: To troubleshoot your error, simplify your code so that it only adds 1 field per run. Afterwards you should be able to identify the faulty lines.

Answer (score 0):

Could ba any numer of problems...

What are you trying to do with the code-lines:

```
this.oField = oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml(taxFieldProcess.toString(), true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
var fieldNumber = clientContext.castTo(oField, SP.FieldNumber);
fieldNumber.update();
```

- you create (in `oField`) a `TaxonomyField`
- you cast (in `fieldNumber`) the `TaxonomyField` to `NumberField` (I *think* this breaks your code)
- you update `fieldNumber`

**First** I would remove all the `this.oField =`-stuff, as you're not using it anyhow.
**Second** I would try adding one field to the list and see if that works. Work your way up to all the fields from there.

You could also check on the last usage of `oField`: You always assing `this.oField`, but in the `var fieldNumber`-Line you access `oField` without `this`. The two need not be the same...

Comment: I found the problom and its when i try to set lookup column to another list i have.

Comment: What is the value of `gnPagesId`? I _think_ it should be something like `{5D184D01-082C-4831-8757-CA2C98F05221}` - including the baces and dashes..

Answer (score 0):

I found the problom and the error is because of lookup Field to another list i have. These lines are giving the error:

```
var lookupSchema = "<Field Type='Lookup' DisplayName='GNPage' Name='GNPage' StaticName='GNPage' List='" + gnPagesId + "' ShowField='Title' RelationshipDeleteBehavior='None' />";
        oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml(lookupSchema, true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
```

All other Fields get created if i comment out these lines above.....